# Does facebook open graph apps have to support english

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, multilingual

I have finish coding a apps with vietnamese language, and also set up some action + object. Now i just want to publish my apps for only Vietnamese. I have some question here below:

Does it need to create multi-languages (english & vietnamese) so that facebook could approve my 'action' apps?

Answer (score 1):

The actions won't be approved unless they're submitted (And make sense) in English, but you can internationalise the app - via the methods outlined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/internationalization/